# How to implement a conditional random field based energy function from images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, crf

I am trying to implement some segmentation tool for my images, and I am trying to use conditional random field (CRF) based method. For example, in [this paper](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D4497207&ei=LfWrU52eO8TBPIrHgIgO&usg=AFQjCNHDO9nr4-TwsYhRmn1eCwh3RAamvw&sig2=KHaSgS2eqvYHr2e3g50a5Q&bvm=bv.69837884,d.ZGU).

The standard CRF energy function includes two parts, i.e., a unary potential and a pairwise potential

[image: Energy function]

where L are the class labels and X are the observations (image pixels).

I have got some training image with labels of the objects in the image. For example, I have got the ground truth segmentation of the objects in the image with labels.

If I want to use texture of these objects as the feature, I am wondering how to implement and do the training of this energy function? For example, the unary term can be represented by

[image: Unary term]

where v_texture is a vectorised texture feature of each labelled object.

My question is how to implement this log probability function? Using histogram? Thanks. A.

Comment: We cannot answer this question in this scope: many researchers craked their heads for many years cracking this question and there are quite a few ways of doing what you are looking for. Try reading about [textonBoost](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~olga/Courses/Fall2013/CS9840/PossibleStudentPapers/eccv06.pdf). One method that might work for you is using [Decision Tree Feilds](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=152645) that luckly for you has a downloadable package from MSRC.

Comment: Sorry to ask a question seems very broad. But actually, what I want to ask is how to implement the probability density function of a labelled image. For example, passing the image with some filter bank and get textures, then how to implement the PDF? Using Matlab histogram function? Maybe I add too much for the background introduction of the question, but I really didn't want to ask a very big question. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the textonBoost paper? you need to do some learning inorder to get log-probabilities from image patches/descriptors. This is a VERY BRAOD topic.